# How to change a color to specific color

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

How should I change color of icon to a specific color code?
E.g: In the picture I want to change the pink color of checkbox to green 
R:109
G:159
B:24

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace single color](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9411/replace-single-color)

Comment: this was asked so many times already, have you tried searching? https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=replace+color+%5Bphotoshop%5D

Answer (score 1):

- Make a selection around the buttons
- Menu Image → Adjustment → Desaturate
- Make a Solid Color Layer with the RGB settings
- Change the blend mode to Color
- Adjust the Color Layer Mask applying a Minimum Filter

[image]

[image]

Comment: Worked well, final color is almost match with the code